# No need to adhere to local custom?

Tags: halacha-theory, vayeitzei, dina-dmalchusa-dina

When discussing [what permission Yaakov had for rolling the rock off the well](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87266/501),  [Orangesandlemons](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15253/orangesandlemons) quoted a [Shadal](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.29.8?lang=bi&with=Shadal&lang2=bi) (R' Samuel David Luzzatto זצ"ל) that said that Yaakov was under no obligation to adhere to the deal the locals had made about guarding access to the well.

> הנה הוא לא היה מחוייב לשמור התנאי שהתנו ביניהם
>
> (...even if he didn't ask for their permission), Yaakov was under no obligation to adhere to the conditions the shepherds had made between themselves.

(Full quote below)

We have rules such as  *Dina D'Malchusa* - the law of the land is binding, and the concept of *Minhag Hamakom* - deferring to local custom. This explanation of Shadal seems to contradict these common-sense rules; they prevent strangers from causing strife and upsetting the locals.

My question is:
**Can a stranger enter a town and decide some local bylaws aren't applicable to him**?

E.g.: Could a person claim that the laws of *alternate parking* don't apply to him as a visitor; in his hometown there's no such a thing (or it's on a different day)?

> **לא נוכל**: נ"ל לא מחסרון כח כי היו שם שלשה עדרי צאן, והוא רחוק שיעשה יעקב לבדו מה שלא יכלו שלשה אנשים, אבל אמרו לא נוכל מפני התנאי שהתנו ביניהם, שלא יהיה רשות לאחד מן העדרים להשתמש ממימי הבאר בהיותו לבדו. והנה יעקב אולי שאל אם נשארו עדרים אחרים לבא ואמרו לו שלא נשאר אלא עדר רחל, וכשראה אותה מהר וגלל את האבן והשקה את צאנה. ואף אם לא שאל אם נשארו עדרים אחרים שלא באו, **הנה הוא לא היה מחוייב לשמור התנאי שהתנו ביניהם**, ומצד אחר דבר הגון עשה (אף אם לא היתה קרובתו) למהר לפטור את רחל, שהיתה נערה אחת בין כמה אנשים.‏

Comment: Perhaps he is not suggesting that it was the actual local law (as agreed to by *all* who had rights to the well) but rather just an agreement between the shepherds - "התנאי שהתנו ביניהם".

Comment: Why would you assume a priori that a peahat understanding of yaakovs behaviour before mattan Torah would relate to practical halakha millennia later? Is dina dmalkhuta biblical or rabbinic? Particularly if the latter, why would it be relevant to yaakov? Please clarify the question.

Comment: What do you think "Minhag hamakom" is that you think it would apply in this case to yaakov? Please clarify.

Comment: @mevaqesh - I'm perplexed that Shadal would say that a stranger need not adhere to the local _regulations_ - be it from a Torah/Halacha perspective or from a _common decency_ POV.

Comment: @Loewian So Shadal is proposing that strangers can walk into to town and do as they please? See my similar comment to mevaquesh

Comment: Perhaps the agreement they made was specific to the shepherds in the town and not to strangers. If you think about it, they probably were pleased that someone else did the work for them! Think about what they told Ya'akov, namely, "we can't remove the stone until all the groups of sheperds gather..." But Ya'akov was not one of the shepherds. Maybe they were generous to visitors and they let them roll off the stone whenever they wished?

Comment: "Can a stranger enter a town and decide some local bylaws aren't applicable to him?" - In case you haven't noticed, numerous residents think this. It doesn't involve a stranger. But even current halacha states that both minhag hamakom and dina demalchuta wouldn't apply if either overrides a Torah rule. Local law doesn't allow you to speed. But, if you have to get to the hospital in a hurry, b/c you're driving someone suffering a stroke, halacha would ask you to speed.

Comment: In the paragraph you quoted, Shadal says seems to contradict himself. (a) The agreement was that no **one** flock could use the well **alone**. (b) Yaakov asked if more flocks were expected to come, implying that **all flocks** had to be present for the well to be used. Shadal also doesn't explain why the agreement was made or how it was enforced, (considering that according to him, it wasn't particularly difficult to move the stone) so it is difficult to know why Yaakov didn't need to keep to this unexplained agreement.

Comment: Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch suggest that the Arameans mistrusted one another and assumed that if they left the well unguarded, shepherds would take more than their fair share of water. Therefore, they kept a huge stone upon the well which needed several of them to move it. If so, Yaakov was not really going against the rules by moving the stone since there were plenty of shepherds there at the time when he took water for Rachel's flock.

Comment: @AlterBochur - that's all fine, but doesn't address my question of  Shadal's last comment that *a stranger needn't adhere to local bylaws/deals*.

Comment: @DanF - Speeding is irrelevant, locals can also speed in such a case. My question is,  *Can a stranger enter a town and decide some local bylaws aren't applicable to him*, as Shadal seems to suggest?

Comment: @Danny Schoemann I agree. My point was that it is difficult to prove anything about Dina D'Malchusa from Shadal's comment, because he does not explain the terms of the conditions that were agreed upon. If anything, the fact that he does not call it a 'mishpat' or a 'chok' but rather a 'tenai' would imply that it was an arrangement rather than a law.

Comment: Can we, please,  ban the use of the word **CAN** in questions, as it is not clear what practical implication it refers to?

Comment: @AlBerko of course we can. But, it seems that it would greatly limit what people can do when composing questions, here. So, I don't think it makes sense to can the "can".

Comment: "Can a stranger enter a town and decide some local bylaws aren't applicable to him, as Shadal seems to suggest?" that's not how I'm reading the line you bolded at the end. I'm reading it (and I believe this is what @Loewian said as well) as the shepherds made a pact amongst themselves that none of them would water their sheep until all arrived. This doesn't apply to people outside their group. An analogy would be a group of friends who decided that every time they went to a restaurant, they would only order fries. It might be binding on people in that group, but you can get whatever you want!

Comment: @Salmononius2 Yup. You echoed, essentially, my first comment. A *t'nai* is just an agreement, not a town law or any type of law. Can we, perhaps, get a responsible translation of Shada"l? I think that would provide a definitive answer to all this discussion.

Comment: I think you're asking two questions but have combined these into one scenario, here. That may be the problem. The comments seem to focus on your interpretation of Shada"l which you think implies his stating a halacha. I think you need to clarify what you're really seeking, here. Do you want an explanation of Shada"l or do you want to know the general rule (regardless of Shada"l) as to whether one can follow his own rules when visiting?

Comment: @DanF - edited as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be reading too much into Shadal's words. The key point here, I think, is התנאי שהתנו ביניהם – it was an agreement made between the shepherds. They made a mutually beneficial agreement to not take water without all the shepherds present so that water would not be wasted (as Shadal writes earlier: כדי שלא יאבד אחד מהם את המים שלא לצורך).

This does not appear to have been a law, or even a custom. It was an agreement made between various individuals. Each shepherd essentially said "I won't take water alone if you don't take water alone". Yaakov was never party to the agreement so he had no obligation to follow it. The well was apparently not anyone's property, so there was no reason for Yaakov not to use it in whatever way he wanted.

If this is the case, I don't think Shadal's explanation has much bearing on the rules of adhering to local laws and customs.